# deserialize json string with gson

Tags: java, json, jsp, arraylist, gson

My java servlet returns a json string in this way:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();     
String lista = gson.toJson(utenti);
System.out.println(lista);
request.setAttribute("lista", lista);
request.getRequestDispatcher("GestioneUtenti.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

now, in the jsp page I want to have my arrayList again. I try to do this:

```
<%
String lista = (String)request.getAttribute("lista");
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Utente> users = gson.fromJson(lista, TypeToken.get(new ArrayList<Utente>().getClass()).getType());        
out.println(users.get(0).getUsername());
%>
```

I have this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to classi.Utente
```

can Youu help me? If i miss some particulars tell me! thanks :-)

Comment: Try this for your type token - `new TypeToken<ArrayList<Utente>>() {}`.

Comment: Why serialize `utenti` to JSON in the Serlvet and deserialize it back to an `ArrayList`, why not `request.setAttribute("lista", utenti);` directly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved with this code:

```
String lista = (String)request.getAttribute("lista");
Gson gson = new Gson();                         
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Utente>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<Utente> users = new Gson().fromJson(lista, listType);
```

Comment: Best solution i found

Comment: Very helpful... I used it for convert Firebase Remote Config JSON to List of Java Objects. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It suggests you have a StringMap where you have declared a Utente class. The source of the error is more than likely your users list

Comment: I can't understand... the class Utente is defined. I don't know what to put in the second argument of the method fromjson()

Comment: The error is saying that you are expecting a Utente but actually get a StringMap, hence the CCE