# Convert String with json to List

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am trying to convert JSON String (has to be the List) to Object List:

```
[   
    {
        "paramName":"Content-Type",
         "paramValue":"text/xml; charset\u003d\"utf-8\""
    }
]
```

This is my Service.class:

```
String jSONString = new Gson().toJson(systemParams);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<A> map = (List<A>) mapper.readValue(jSONString, A.class);
```

This is my model:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
    public class A {

        String paramName;
        String paramValue;
    }
```

But I obtained exception:

> Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap`

So I tried in different way:

```
A[] map = mapper.readValue(jSONString, A[].class);
```

And I obtained:

> InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of
>   `com.model.A` (no Creators, like default
>   construct, exist):

**UPDATE:**

I tried to change Service.class for:

```
List<A> map = mapper.readValue(jSONString, new TypeReference<List<A>>(){});
```

Still got an exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `com.model.A` (no Creators,
>   like default construct, exist):

So I deleted @AllArgsConstructor annotation and added Constructor manually:

```
   public A(String paramName, String paramValue) {}
```

And still an exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `com.model.A` (no Creators,
>   like default construct, exist):

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert JSON string into List of Java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589381/how-to-convert-json-string-into-list-of-java-object)

Comment: @wowo No, now I have: InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.model.A` (no Creators, like default construct, exist) but I use @Data and @AllArgsConstructor annotations in A.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is written in the error: try to define an empty constructor on the class that have to be deserialized. 
I think also that to serialize the class ( so, the other way, from byte to class) you have to implement the serializable interface.

Comment: I added empty constructor and it works now. Thank you!