# Convert String into list of Pairs: Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, parsing

Is there an easier approach to convert an Intellij IDEA environment variable into a list of Tuples?

My environment variable for Intellij is

```
GROCERY_LIST=[("egg", "dairy"),("chicken", "meat"),("apple", "fruit")]
```

The environment variable gets accessed into Kotlin file as String.

```kotlin
val g_list = System.getenv("GROCERY_LIST")
```

Ideally I'd like to iterate over `g_list`, first element being `("egg", "dairy")` and so on.
And then `("egg", "dairy")` is a tuple/pair

I have tried to split `g_list` by comma that's NOT inside quotes i.e

```kotlin
val splitted_list = g_list.split(",(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*\$)".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
```

this gives me first element as `[("egg",` second element as `"dairy")]` and so on.

Also created a data class and tried to map the string into data class using `jacksonObjectMapper` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589381/how-to-convert-json-string-into-list-of-java-object) link:

```kotlin
val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
val g_list = System.getenv("GROCERY_LIST")
val myList: List<Shopping> = mapper.readValue(g_list)

data class Shopping(val a: String, val b: String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create a regular expression to match all strings in your environmental variable.
   [`Regex::findAll()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find-all.html)
2. Then loop through the strings while creating a list of `Shopping` objects.

```
// Raw data set.
val groceryList: String = "[(\"egg\", \"dairy\"),(\"chicken\", \"meat\"),(\"apple\", \"fruit\")]"

// Build regular expression.
val regex = Regex("\"([\\s\\S]+?)\"")
val matchResult = regex.findAll(groceryList)
val iterator = matchResult.iterator()

// Create a List of `Shopping` objects.
var first: String = "";
var second: String = "";
val shoppingList = mutableListOf<Shopping>()
var i = 0;

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    val value = iterator.next().value;

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        first = value;
    } else {
        second = value;
        shoppingList.add(Shopping(first, second))
        first = ""
        second = ""
    }

    i++

}

// Print Shopping List.
for (s in shoppingList) {
    println(s)
}

// Output.
/*
    Shopping(a="egg", b="dairy")
    Shopping(a="chicken", b="meat")
    Shopping(a="apple", b="fruit")
*/

data class Shopping(val a: String, val b: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never a good idea to use regex to match parenthesis.

I would suggest a step-by-step approach:

You could first match the name and the value by

```
(\w+)=(.*)
```

There you get the name in group 1 and the value in group 2 without caring about any subsequent `=` characters that might appear in the value.

If you then want to split the value, I would get rid of start and end parenthesis first by matching by

```
(?<=\[\().*(?=\)\])
```

(or simply cut off the first and last two characters of the string, if it is always given it starts with `[(` and ends in `)]`)

Then get the single list entries from splitting by

```
\),\(
```

(take care that the split operation also takes a regex, so you have to escape it)

And for each list entry you could split that simply by

```
,\s*
```

or, if you want the quote character to be removed, use a *match* with

```
\"(.*)\",\s*\"(.*)\"
```

where group 1 contains the key (left of equals sign) and group 2 the value (right of equals sign)